# how to remotely install certificate on Windows CE using RAPI and ActiveSync

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, windows-ce, activesync, rapi

I'm creating .NET application which connects to WindowsCE device using Active Sync. I'm using OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication.dll library to connect via RAPI but I didn't find any way to install the certificate on the mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAPI has no inherent previsions for installing certificates.  it does, however, have the ability to use your own [custom RAPI methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917422.aspx) that you can [Invoke](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/communication/OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication.RAPI.Invoke.html).  You could push the cert down and use a custom RAPI DLL (that you also push down) to do the install.

You could also roll the cert info [into a CSP](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vik/archive/2006/09/21/using-windows-mobile-csp-_2800_sync-configuration-service-provider_2900_.aspx) and then put that in a CAB that you deploy and execute.  The advantage there is that you don't need a custom RAPI DLL.

Comment: I would rather go for CSP because it seems to be less painful. The problem is that when I try to run created CAB file, I get the message: "file installCert.cab is not valid Windows CE Setup file". Any ideas why? I couldn't download makecab.exe from the link (not available anymore), but I found this program in Visual Studio SDK: "Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\SDKTools\makecab.exe"